# Checking if entire object exists in db with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have the following object:

```
var person = {
    fname: "Joe",
    lname: "Shmoe",
    misc: {
        age: "25",
        gender: "M",
        hair: "blonde"
    }
}
```

and I need to check whether this exact person is in the database using mongoose. What I'd like to do is something along the lines of

```
Person.findOne(person, function(err, result) {
    if (!result) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check if an entire object exists as a document in the database using mongoose without manually entering in all of the fields?

edit: Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
Person.findOne({ fname: person.fname })
    .where('lname').equals(person.lname)
    .where('misc.age').equals(person.misc.age)
    .where('misc.gender').equals(person.misc.gender)
    .where('misc.hair').equals(person.misc.hair)
    .exec(function(err, result) {
        if (!result) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manually entering the fields"? That seems to be your actual question. How are you currently doing this? Please show the code that currently implements this and what you would like to do.

Comment: You're right, that wasn't super clear. Just added an edit.

Comment: Was there something lacking in the answer that did not explain how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking here as if you just pass in the `person` variable you have defined as the first argument for the query then you will get the result that does exactly match. The proviso there is that the keys in "misc" must be in the same order within your actual document or you are otherwise required to use the "dot notation" if that order was not always the same:

```
{ 
    "fname": "Joe",
    "lname": "Schmoe",
    "misc.age": "25",
    "misc.gender": "M",
    "misc.hair": "blonde"
}
```

And that you not be hard to convert from your initial object:

```
var obj = {};

for ( var k in person ) {
    if ( "k" == "misc" ) {
        for ( var b in person[k] ) {
            obj["misc." + b] person[k][b];
        }
    } else {
        obj[k] = person[k];
    }
}
```

Then you can use `obj` as your query argument as it has the "dot notation" form:

Generally though the case is that it should be okay, unless you have cast to a Mongoose document with a differing `_id` value. Some code to demonstrate this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    async = require('async'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

var personSchema = new Schema({
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  misc: {
    age: String,
    gender: String,
    hair: String
  }
});

var Person = mongoose.model( "Person", personSchema, "person" );

var data = {
  fname: "Joe",
  lname: "Shmoe",
  misc: {
    age: "25",
    gender: "M",
    hair: "blonde"
  }
};

var person = new Person( data );
var other = new Person( data );

console.log( person );

async.series([
  function(callback) {
    person.save(function(err,person) {
      callback();
    });
  },
  function(callback) {

    console.log( "This works" );
    Person.findOne( data, function(err,person) {
      console.log( "person: " + person );
      callback();
    });
  },
  function(callback) {

    console.log( "This doesn't" );
    Person.findOne( other, function(err,person) {
      console.log( "person: " + person );
      callback();
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    console.log( "This does" );
    var obj = other.toObject();
    delete obj._id;
    Person.findOne( obj, function(err,person) {
      console.log( "person: " + person );
      callback();
    });
  },
]);
```